# Stock android browser on android 4.1.1

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer

Can I remove icon for this from my start up screen? Am using android 4.1.1 on asus transformer'prime tf201.
Also can I make firefox my default with an icon on start up screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to root your phone if you wish to uninstall the pre-installed stock Android browser. You can download a launcher from the Play Store that can let you hide apps. Also, when tapping on a link it should usually ask you "open with..." and you can tap Firefox, and then tap Always. For this, you must have already installed Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to remove the icon hold it and drag up to remove. Then click apps, and go to Google play store to download Mozilla Firefox. Finally once installed this should create a shortcut. Otherwise look for it in apps and hold it down to drag to the home screen. Additionally you may be able to go to settings General defaults and see if you can select the browser as a default.